# Correct way to power an 8 ohm speaker

Tags: signal, oscillator, circuit-design, speakers

I designed and simulated a tone generator of some sort using multism. I got some parts of the circuit online. When I tested it on a breadboard, the speaker didn't make any sounds. ere is the circuit:
[image]

Here is the resulting wave across the 8 ohm resistor(speaker):

[image]

Here is the simulation results:
[image]

Comment: If you have an osciliscope, then you could start by checking the output of the 741 to see if it is oscillating.  Depending on that result, you know whether the oscillator or the amplifier has a problem.

Comment: Since you are working on a breadboard, you might have wired something incorrectly.  Double check to be sure everything is right.  Also check voltages on the power inputs the the 741 and to the transistors.

Comment: @JRE I built it twice on the breadboard and now i'm frustrated. Only other option is to try an oscilloscope. Thanks

Comment: Check the voltages with a multimeter first.  That may be enough to find the problem.

Comment: At 1 kHz, many multimeters will be able to detect it too but oscilloscope is your friend.